# Regular expression for validating a QLineEdit

Tags: regex, pyqt4

I don't know re but I want to set a validator for a QlineEdit. 
     rule = QRegExp(r"")
I want that a string which should be allowed to enter in line edit must have these things.

1. Must start with 'A' or 'a'
2. after wards numbers

Comment: You can find all the information regarding this at http://www.regular-expressions.info . Use Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following regular expression:

```
r'^[Aa]\d+$`
```

- `^`, `$` matches the beginning / end of the string.
- `[Aa]` matches `A` or `a`.
- `\d` matches a digit. `\d+` matches one or more digits.